# Does retrieving an object from Doctrine2 cause __construct() of the model class to run?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

When I retrieve an object say by

```
$em->find('Application\Models\User', 1);
```

or other methods like DQL, `findBy*()` cause the `__construct()` of the model class to run? I am having a problem where I set variables there like reference to EntityManager and I find that its not set.

I tried putting a `die()` in `__construct()` and it doesn't halt the application. Can I say that if I want to set other properties/fields like `EntityManager $em` I have to do it some other way? Perhaps something like

```
protected function getEm() {
    if (!isset($this->em)) {
        $this->em = \Zend_Registry::get('em');
    }
    return $this->em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doctrine2 documentation Doctrine2 never calls __construct() method of entities.
http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/architecture.html?highlight=construct

I think you should'nt refer to entityManager in the entity class, maybe use a service class for this .